# Создание своего шаблона для LXC (Proxmox)

Tags: debian, шаблоны, lxc

Доброго времени суток всем!
Виртуализация - Proxmox. Хочу свой шаблон для контейнеров создать, используя debootstrap.
Пытался сделать по [этой](http://aronpodrigal.blogspot.com/2015/12/creating-customized-template-for-use.html) статье. Контейнер создаётся, но не запускается. Возможно, упущена какая-то деталь.
В общих чертах алгоритм следующий:
1. debootstrap --variant=minbase --arch=amd64 stretch debian-mini http://deb.debian.org/debian/
2. <какие-либо_шаги_по_настройке>
3. sudo tar -c[v]pzf mylxc.tar.gz -C debian-mini .
4. Использование шаблона mylxc.tar.gz

Помогите, уважаемые гуру!

Answer (score 0):

https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Debian_Appliance_Builder

1. На ноде Proxmox установить dab: apt install dab
2. mkdir /mnt/debian-mini && cd /mnt/debian-mini/
3. Создать файл dab.conf с содержимым:

   Suite: stretch
   Architecture: amd64
   Name: stretch
   Version: 9.9-1
   Section: system
   Maintainer: I
   Description: Debian 9.9
    Debian 9.9 Stretch
4. dab init
5. dab bootstrap --minimal
6. dab finalize
7. mv debian-9.0-stretch_9.9-1_amd64.tar.gz /var/lib/vz/template/cache/
8. dab clean
9. dab dist-clean

Comment: круто, но какая деталь была упущена?

Comment: Это другой подход в принципе, на основе использования пакета dab (Debian Appliance Builder).